# Execute JS File Outside Casperjs Folder

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I got a problem...
I'm using casperjs 1.1.0 beta3
I already set the phantom and casperjs path in system variable in windows 8.1
I try to run js code which placed in different folder from casperjs folder. I got the execution time takes so long.
But when I put my js code in samples folder in casperjs folder, the execution time takes so fast.
Why this is happened?
So how if I want to execute js file with casperjs command fastly without put my js code into casperjs folder?
Any suggestion or explanation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is probably something else at work here. The only thing that I can think of is if you take a lot of screenshots and when running *outside casperjs folder* you actually run on a network drive.

Comment: The first time casperjs and phantomjs starts in a console window does indeed take a few seconds to warm up. The second time you run its much quicker.... Can you confirm its `SLOW` every time you run in the same console window? I have win 8.1 and have different folders and experience no slowness